# Add source and layer from GeoJSON data in flutter mapbox gl

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I'm building a simple Flutter application using the **mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0** plugin.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh4Mp.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh4Mp.png
So basically i have a GeoJSON data, which i need to add in rendered map as source and apply a Fill Layer based on source (GeoJSON) property. Currently feature with fill layer is showing properly, but when try to get the feature or any feature details when user click on feature layer,it shows the "id" blank.

I've reviewed the Mapbox Maps documentation, but I couldn't find a clear example for achieving this specific functionality. Any assistance or code snippets would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Here is my code snippets,

```
/* view code */
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';
import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: Get.height,
          child: MapboxMap(
            onMapCreated: (mapcontroller) {
              controller.onMapCreated(mapcontroller);
            },
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            accessToken:
                "<MAPBOX ACCESS TOKEN>",
            initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(47.616100673, -107.882000467), zoom: 10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
/* view code */

/* controller code */
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  String geojsonString = "";

  // Create a Map to store colors based on status
  Map<int, Color> statusColors = {
    1: const Color.fromARGB(128, 221, 143, 137), // 50% opacity
    2: const Color.fromARGB(128, 68, 235, 73), // 50% opacity
    3: const Color.fromARGB(128, 14, 125, 215), // 50% opacity
    4: Colors.transparent, // Custom color for status 4
  };

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}

  Future<void> loadGeoJSON() async {
    geojsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/geo.geojson');
  }

  void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController mapboxMap) async {
    // Create a Map to store colors based on status
    Map<int, Color> statusColors = {
      1: const Color.fromARGB(128, 221, 143, 137), // 50% opacity
      2: const Color.fromARGB(128, 68, 235, 73), // 50% opacity
      3: const Color.fromARGB(128, 14, 125, 215), // 50% opacity
      4: Colors.transparent, // Custom color for status 4
    };

    // Add the GeoJSON source to the map
    await mapboxMap.addSource("fills", GeojsonSourceProperties(data: geojson));

    // Add the fill layer with the specified color and filter
    await mapboxMap.addFillLayer(
      "fills",
      "fills",
      const FillLayerProperties(
        fillColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)', // Use a valid color string
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
      ),
      filter: [
        '==',
        ['get', 'status'],
        1 // Note: Removed quotes around 1 to compare with a number
      ],
    );

    mapboxMap.onFeatureTapped.add((id, point, coordinates) {
      // Check if the tapped feature is part of the "fills" layer
      if (id != null && id is String && id.startsWith('fills')) {
        // Extract the original feature ID
        String originalFeatureId = id.replaceAll('fills.', '');
        print(
            'Tapped feature with original ID - $originalFeatureId, Point - $point, Coordinates - $coordinates');
      }
    });
  }
  
}
/* controller code*/

/* sample GeoJSON */
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -107.900000467,
              47.598100673
            ],
            [
              -107.891000467,
              47.598100673
            ],
            [
              -107.891000467,
              47.589100673
            ],
            [
              -107.900000467,
              47.589100673
            ],
            [
              -107.900000467,
              47.598100673
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "dbId": "5",
        "status": 4,
        "uid": null,
        "isBlocked": 0,
        "id": "5",
        "left": -107.900000467,
        "top": 47.598100673,
        "right": -107.891000467,
        "bottom": 47.589100673
      }
    },...    
  ]
}
/* sample GeoJSON code */
```

Comment: you can check example code here https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/b2bfef669e42397704b6f43d55b5df67b18c0fa8/example/lib/layer.dart#L67

Comment: @chunhunghan Hello, you were a huge help. I am still having trouble with the last step, which has to do with retrieving feature details (such as the ID) when a user clicks on a feature layer. I tried to edit my question. Can you help me out? BTW, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Do you mean feature id? your sample GeoJSON do not have "id" field and "properties": <String, dynamic>{'id': 0}, see this https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/b2bfef669e42397704b6f43d55b5df67b18c0fa8/example/lib/layer.dart#L205

Comment: @chunhunghan Of course, I see now. How can I get to the "id" that is stored inside my properties?

Comment: @chunhunghan Sir, As an additional note, even though this is probably kind of unrelated, I am not too familiar with stackoverflow questions and such. I would appreciate it if you could review my question and offer any suggestions for improving its coherence going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code works fine for me!

- I modified my GeoJSON data and added the "id" field inside "feature" instead of "properties".

```dart
void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController mapboxMap) async {
    // await getJson();

    // Create a Map to store colors based on status
    Map<int, String> statusColors = {
      1: convertColorToRgba(const Color.fromARGB(128, 221, 143, 137), 1),
      2: convertColorToRgba(const Color.fromARGB(128, 68, 235, 73), 1),
      3: convertColorToRgba(const Color.fromARGB(128, 14, 125, 215), 1),
      4: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.0)', // Transparent color for status 4
    };

    // Add the GeoJSON source to the map
    await mapboxMap.addSource("fills", GeojsonSourceProperties(data: geojson));

    // Add the fill layer with the specified color and filter
    await mapboxMap.addFillLayer(
      "fills",
      "fills",
      FillLayerProperties(
        fillColor: [
          "step", ["get", "status"],
          statusColors[1], 1,
          statusColors[2], 2,
          statusColors[3], 3,
          statusColors[4], 4,
          'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.0)' // Default color
        ],
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        fillOutlineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      ),
      filter: [
        "has",
        "status"
      ], // Add filter to only render features with a "status" property
      enableInteraction: true,
    );
    
    update();
  }
```